# When should Native Numbers be used?

Tags: hanja, korean-to-english, numbers, sino-korean-words

When you are numbering things, like pages, which set of Korean numbers would one use? Also, when counting objects, which are you supposed to use? I have seen people specify months, phone numbers, years, etc. but never these.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I need to use the native vs Sino-Korean numerals?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/154/when-do-i-need-to-use-the-native-vs-sino-korean-numerals)

Answer (score 1):

For pages, I guess you can say several ways. For example, to count from 1 to 10, you can either

한 페이지
두 페이지
세 페이지
...
열 페이지

or you can say

첫번째 페이지
두번째 페이지
세번째 페이지
...

or simply

한장
두장
세장
네장
...
열장

oh well.. now you can so

한 페이지
두 페이지
세 페이지
네 페이지
...
열 페이지

For counting objects, it also depends on what kind of "object" is it. However, in general, you can use "개", it will be

한개
두개
세개
네개
...
열개

or maybe

하나
둘
셋
넷
..
열

could also work.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

https://ko.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%88%98%EC%82%AC_(%ED%92%88%EC%82%AC) (wikipedia about 한국어 수사 - 수 meaning number(s), 사 meaning word.)

So it definitely says over 100 often uses 한수사(한 meaning from chinese character, 수사 I already explained), for example, **백한** 마리 달마시안, **삼천만** 원 and as a native Korean speaker I can confirm I’ve never seen such a case that does not use 한수사 over number 100. (Although that doesn’t mean there’s no 고유슈사 representing 100 - it is rarely used nowadays.)

Number zero is also apparent - the only numbering word that represents 0 is 한수사 ‘영’.

Under 100 I can say 고유수사(the Korean-original numbering words) are regularly used like 나는 두 마리의 개를 키운다, 나는 시험에 세번 떨어졌다, but not always. For example - months(팔월), $5(오 달러), etc. I can definitely tell which numbering should be used when the category is specified, but I can’t tell the rule defining them.

Also, it is good to note that when some numbers that are not number-ish, like phone number 한수사 is used for pronunciation but when it is not acknowledged properly sometimes 고유수사 is used, for example:

A: 전화번호가 어떻게 되시죠?

B: 공이-일이일이-....

A: 일이일... 다음에 뭐라고 하셨나요?

B: 하나-둘-하나-둘이요.