# Why Korean numbers when counting forward, but Sino numbers when counting backward?

Tags: numbers

https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/159 doesn't answer my question also mooted on [HiNative](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/3520802). This distinction feels illogical and senseless to me. What's the reason or rationale?

Here's one example from Girls' Generation. When they introduce themselves, they always count forward  — 하나 , 둘, 셋, we are Girls' Generation. But Yu Ri Kwon counts backwards at [13:57](https://youtu.be/qoo7Tdyn5sY?t=837)  — 삼, 이 , 일.

Comment: To make it more complicated — You can also say “일, 이, 삼, 사, ….” (with Sino-numbers) to count seconds. And [native Korean numbers can also be used to count backwards.](https://youtu.be/wDONf1UmX88?t=125)

Comment: 그냥 버릇이에요. 순우리말로 카운트다운하는 경우는 아주 드문데 탑블레이드라는 한국 만화 보면 나옵니다. "셋, 둘, 하나, 고우 슛"

Answer (score 2):

#### They don’t know, too.

As to why no one answers this question asked a week ago, it’s because it’s something native speakers would find natural but don’t know the exact rules for that.

#### Don’t sweat it though.

It’s just a tendency, if not preference, however; you can use both native and Sino–numbers to count forwards or backwards *if that doesn’t involve units* (“if you don’t say units when counting”). Both sound good.

---

This doesn’t quite answer your question, please accept another one that’s more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll ever find a logical or rational answer to this. Why use native numbers for somethings and Sino-Korean numbers for others? Why read the hour natively, but the minutes in Sino-Korean? Language is not always rational or logical and many times the rule is